# WooCommerce querying all products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, transient

There is a website that shows products from thousands of e-shops.
The way they get the products of all these e-shops is via XML file.

I created my XML file which contains all of my 2k+ products.

In order for me to create this XML product list, I made a BIG query that lists every single product with its variables and every variation that a variable has.

The whole query takes about 30-40 seconds to finish and generate my XML file.

But sometimes when server is quite busy, the process fails because the memory is too high at busy times. I have bumped memory limit to 132MB and max_execution_time to 60 seconds. But I still get random fails from generating the XML file from time to time.

What should I do to make the query faster? I've read a lot about Transient API. You think it's a good idea to use it? The 3rd party website that I'm sending the XML file is requesting it every 1 hour. So I made a cron job for my server to re-create the XML every 1 hour just so the file always has the new products or any value that is changed.

My main issue is how can I make the querying of all variations/variables faster?

This is how I am building my XML in case you guys think the process is not performant:

```
// Create the XML file
$myFile = fopen("skroutz.xml", "w+");

// XML Headers
$ex .= "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
$ex .= "<mywebstore>";
$ex .= "<created_at>" . date("Y-m-d H:i") . "</created_at>";
$ex .= "<products>";

// Loop through products
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 113,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    ) )
) );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){  // Check if product is Variable

...

}

endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();


$ex .= "</products>";
$ex .= '</mywebstore>';

fwrite($myFile, $ex);
fclose($myFile);
```

Comment: If you absolutely cannot increase the memory limit and max_execution_time on your hosting, you could split the query into chunks (e.g., 500 posts_per_page at a time), storing the query's offset in a transient. If the transient `offset` does not exists yet, create an empty XML file with header. After looping through the first 500 results, store the offset in the transient where you will resume upon next invocation of the PHP script. For 2000 products this would require calling the script 4 times. You can automate this by enforcing a refresh (meta tag/JS) for offset + 500 < found_posts.

Comment: Damn, these all sound too advanced for me to code. You think the code above is correct way that im creating the XML file? And the only better performant way would be to use Transients?

Comment: Transients have nothing to do with query performance. They're just like options, but with a best-before date automatically deleted on expiry.

Comment: Yes you are right. Even if I create Transients I wouldn't get any benefit performance-wise. I just wanted to know if the method I use with `$ex .=` appending content inside the file is correct.

Answer (score 1):

So, this isn't going to be a fully working (or tested) example, but you might get enough hints from this:

```
define('XML_FILE', 'skroutz.xml');
define('QUERY_LIMIT', 500);
$query_offset = get_transient('xml_query_offset');
if (($query_offset === false) || !is_numeric($query_offset)) {
  // -- (re-)start the query initially, write a new XML file --
  $query_offset = 0;
  ob_start();
  // XML Headers
?>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<mywebstore>
<created_at><?= date("Y-m-d H:i") ?></created_at>
<products>
<?php
  file_put_contents(XML_FILE, ob_get_clean()); // flush buffer to new XML file
}

// Loop through products (from $query_offset)
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'offset' => $query_offset,
    'posts_per_page' => QUERY_LIMIT,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => 113,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    ) )
) );

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){  // Check if product is Variable

...

}
file_put_contents(XML_FILE, $GENERATED_XML_CONTENT, FILE_APPEND); // append product's XML code to the end of the file

endwhile;
endif;

if (($query_offset + QUERY_LIMIT) >= $loop->found_posts) {
  // you've reached the end, delete the transient
  delete_transient('xml_query_offset');
  file_put_contents(XML_FILE, '</products>'.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND); // close the products XML tag, finally.
  // we're done.
} else {
  $query_offset += QUERY_LIMIT;
  set_transient('xml_query_offset', $query_offset, 5 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS);
  // we will force a reload via JS (assuming the front-end output is HTML)
?>
<script>
location.reload(true); // bypass cache
</script>
<?php
}
wp_reset_query();
```

The overall idea is to detect if the code has run within the past 5 minutes (transient timeout). If it didn't, this means you want to generate a new XML-file. I personally prefer using output buffering instead of appending to the `$ex` variable writing that to a file. You can then use `file_put_contents` either without `FILE_APPEND` to make a new file, or just append to the already existing content.

Performance-wise, writing to the file (doesn't matter which way) is **not** your bottleneck here but rather the WP query and the loop. This means you shorten the loop limiting the results. After the last block is done, you close the XML tag and delete the transient. I'm not sure if that awkward JS auto-reload will actually work or if you have to manually call it again.

Comment: Thanks alot for the info! I will try to implement it and see how it goes!